# How to load url along with saved Cookies in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I would like to load my url using **javascript**, Where my url is required authorization token. The token already saved in cookies with the following code.

```
<script>
function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
  var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
  document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

function getCookie(cname) {
  var name = cname + "=";
  var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
  var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
  for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return "";
}
</script>
```

And able to get saved token from cookies successfully but not able to apply for my url load which is required authentication token.

Can any one suggest me a way to load url with authorization token from cookies.

**NOTE:** I can not pass the authorization token in url as parameter.

Here is my url loading code:

```
<script>
function newDoc() {
  window.location.assign("https://mydomine.com/Viewer?type=xyz")
}
</script>
```

Comment: Are you trying to set a cookie for a different domain?

Comment: If so, you'll need to set the cookie domain https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#Syntax

Comment: It is not possible to retrieve your cookie from one domain and use it on a other domain.
The only solution I see is to send your cookie as a parameter in the URL, but you've already mentioned that this is not possible.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. @Dontwan yes. phuzi i will check the above mentioned link.

Comment: @phuzi really appreciate's , if you provide example scripts

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to set the cookie for a different domain, then you'll need to add the domain information to the cookie.

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays, domain) {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
  var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
  var cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
  // Add the domain, if specified.
  if (domain) {
    cookie += `;domain={domain}`
  }
  document.cookie = cookie;
}
```

Comment: i have tried your suggestion, but still my web page not loading with auth token. any clues on this.